# Let's encrypt Failed authorization procedure

Tags: python, nginx

I'm using Debian 9 and NGINX to deploy my app Django.
When I type:

`sudo certbot --nginx -d example.com -d www.example.com`

I get the next error:

```
Failed authorization procedure. example.com (http-01): 
urn:acme:error:tls :: The server experienced a TLS error during domain 
verification :: Fetching https://example.com/.well-known/acme- 
challenge/H9WJVzPYJ93jewGJjkUFFKQJBJ8-YT7t9z-Sw_PQQUg: remote error: tls: 
internal error

IMPORTANT NOTES:
- The following errors were reported by the server:

Domain: example.com
Type:   tls
Detail: Fetching
https://example.com/.well-known/acme- 
challenge/H9WJVzPYJ93jewGJjkUFFKQJBJ8-YT7t9z-Sw_PQQUg:
remote error: tls: internal error

To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
contain(s) the right IP address. Additionally, please check that
you have an up-to-date TLS configuration that allows the server to
communicate with the Certbot client.
```

I do not know what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: Are you actually trying to issue a certificate for example.com, or did you sanitize the output of your command? Because I doubt you control example.com.

Comment: I sanitized the output.